# How to set a walkthrough/introduction screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am new developer and I am struggling with my Walkthrough screen for my application.
I have created it, but when I click continue to my main screen, the app crashes.
Here is the code I have under my "continue" button:

```
  @IBAction func skipButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    let nextView: FirstViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController

    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate


    appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = nextView

}
```

and the error I get is :

```
 Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x19f33c0d8) to 'Iwin.FirstViewController' (0x100057220).
```

I think the Problem is in the name of the name of the identifier which in my case is "FirstViewController"

This is the storyboard ID of my TabBarController, which should be the first screen of my app.

Attached  I have uploaded a picture too.

Comment: I have got a code on GitHub that does a similar job. 
Here's the link: https://github.com/karanthakakr04/Walkthrough-Demo.git
I hope it serves your need. Also there's this reference tutorial if someone needs it: https://youtu.be/tNCsQe5vfRk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing probably has to do with the forced conversion (`as!`) you do on the first line of the function. You're doing the following:

1. Calling `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`, which Apple API Documentation says returns `UIViewController` (in this case, it's returning `UITabBarController`, a subclass)
2. [Force converting](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23) a `UITabBarController` to a `FirstViewController`, which fails.

This is because forced conversion guarantees that the resulting value won't be `nil`, but it doesn't guarantee that it won't fail (crash). `UITabBarController` is simply not convertible, because it does not extend/implement `FirstViewController`.

My guess is that even though you've given that view controller the **identifier** `"FirstViewController"`, but it's just a regular old `UITabBarController`. Double check in Interface Builder that this View Controller is actually an instance of your `FirstViewController` class.

Looking at your photo, the "Class" field has the default value of `UITabBarController` -- this should be the first thing you try to change. Fill in `FirstViewController`, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry How can I check it?
I tried to change the class to FirstViewCOntroller but it is not possible

Comment: Is `FirstViewController` a subclass of `UITabBarController`? Otherwise you probably won't be able to -- make `FirstViewController` a subclass of `UITabBarController` if needed.

Comment: It is, FirstViewController is the first screen on my app and it is a subclass of the UITabBarController

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example so I can see your problem for myself?

Comment: Is that what you need?

Comment: From struct city below:)

Comment: Alright. Just as suspected, `FirstViewController` is **not** a subclass of `UITabBarController`:

Comment: How can I make it a subclass then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126940/discussion-between-phrz-and-ivan).